# Reactive Form patchpatch value error when no value provided

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I got this problem that I don't get it.
I have a `formGroup` with few controls, here is a simplified code:

### .ts

```
form = new FormGroup({
   firstName: new FormControl(''),
   lastName: new FormControl('')
})
```

### .html

```
<input type="text" formControlName="firstName" />
<input type="text" formControlName="lastName" />
```

So, when I get the request back from the API, I only have this:

```
{ 
 firstName: "Johny"
}
```

Which is fine, the request is correct because in this case Johny didn't provide his last name.

I'm using `patchValue` to fill the form with the data I received from the API, the problem is that I get this error:

```
ERROR Error: NG01002: Must supply a value for form control with name: 'lastName'
```

Which is correct, I'm not providing that value, but is there a way around it? Or my only options is to always create the object first, giving empty string values and then modifying them accordingly?

Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

It should be okay to miss some values when using `patchValue()` as stated here in the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#updating-parts-of-the-data-model).

Try using the spread operator when passing an object as a parameter

```
this.formGroup.patchValue(...myObj);
```

Comment: Hey @Nader thanks, but when I do that I get `A spread argument must either have a tuple type or be passed to a rest parameter.`

Comment: Sorry, I forget the parenthesis, `{...myObj}`. @MrRobot

Comment: I tried that as well :( same error as before :(

Comment: That's weird, as a work a round try smth like
`patchValue({firstName: data.firstName})`

Comment: I know right? I'm pretty sure I have done something like that before and this time it's giving me this problem. :/

Comment: I think I know what is causing the problem but haven't quite figured out. I think it's because I have nested forms.

Comment: Yest this could be possible I think, try smth like 
`parentForm.get('childForm').patchValue()`

Comment: I tried that.. no dice :( it's something else.. but thank you so much for your help thou

Answer (score 0):

To anyone falling over this in the future: You're trying to patch/set the value for all controls in the `FormGroup`. Angular therefore expects you to provide a value for each control.

The correct way would be instead to access the controls and set the value through there:

```
this.formGroup.get('firstName').patchValue("Johny")
```